# Unable to find where is function define in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This code is used for getting value of home_page_left_box

get('home_page_left_box',1,1,$GLOBALS['settings'])

couldn't find where it is defined.

Comment: where which is defined? get? `home_page_left_box`? `$GLOBALS['settings']`?

Comment: there are couple of way of searching, first use a Eclipse IDE, and right click on function to find it;s defination. Second, use a FILE Search feature of available in most text editor for programming and search for "function <functionname>" since it is define only once or couple of times you will get all file related to it.

Comment: Get function is used taking code of home_pagae_left_box (html code) home page_left_box is passed in get function and 3 more values passed i want to see where it is defined. and my file is at server.
And i don't know why $GLOBALS['setting'] is used

Comment: It was Left Box of home page.

I find it at wpadmin->theme setting-> my theme

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do a

```
grep -ri -e 'function.* get *(' sourcedirectory
```

?

Comment: What is this? how to use it?

Comment: @DeepakManwal, [grep](https://www.google.com/search?q=grep) or [grep](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=grep)